# Import .txt to DataGridView (14 Columns separated by Space) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to import a .txt file into DataGridView where each column is separated by a space, but the problem lies in the last column. The last column contains spaces that shouldn't be evaluated as a "Split" (See Below).

> `' 1    2    3      4    5   6   7     8      9      10     11      12      13     14
>   SAT 0901 133000 1330 0002 002 003 000030 000000 00000000 000 00000C174BB 0000 This One`

```
Private Sub ImpData(ByRef selectedFile As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    For d = 1 To 14
        dt.Columns.Add(d, GetType(String))
    Next
    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(selectedFile)
    Dim colCount = 14

    For Each line In lines
        Dim objFields = From field In line.Split(" "c)
                        Select field
        Dim newRow = dt.Rows.Add()
        newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MetroButton1.Click

    Dim selectedfile As String = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    selectedfile = Path.GetFullPath(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    txtTEST1.Text = selectedfile
    ImpData(selectedfile)
End Sub
```

"Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table." Is the error being thrown because of the Last Column of each Row. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are the strings in columns 1 to 13 of fixed length?

Comment: Yes. Columns 1 to 13 are fixed length with Column 14 being more or less a description column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is working for me as a possible solution. Please note this is coded quick and dirty. Please have a look at OOP too e.g. [Object Oriented Programming By Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15572/OO-Programming-By-Example).

```
Private Sub ImpData(ByRef selectedFile As String)
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  For d = 1 To 14
    dt.Columns.Add(d, GetType(String))
  Next
  Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(selectedFile)
  '-- Dim colCount = 16

  For Each line In lines
    Dim sLinePart1 As String = line.Substring(0, 77)
    Dim sLinePart2 As String = line.Substring(78, line.Length - 78)
    Dim objFields = From field In sLinePart1.Split(" "c) Select field
    Dim newRow = dt.Rows.Add()
    newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()
    newRow(13) = sLinePart2
  Next
  DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Please note I don't have two spaces in the lines.

```
SAT 0901 133000 1330 0002 002 003 000030 000000 00000000 000 00000C174BB 0000 This One first
SAT 0901 133000 1330 0002 002 003 000030 000000 00000000 000 00000C174BB 0000 This One second
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly for what I need.